Bukkit -> Forge network messages
I send the packet via the Bukkit plugin. Package Send Code:
        try {
            String full_msg = "Text(" + message + ")";
            byte[] data = full_msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            MinecraftKey channel = new MinecraftKey("chilove", "main");

            PacketContainer packet = new PacketContainer(PacketType.Play.Server.CUSTOM_PAYLOAD);
            packet.getMinecraftKeys().write(0, channel);

            ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(data);
            Object serializer = MinecraftReflection.getPacketDataSerializer(byteBuf);

            packet.getModifier().withType(ByteBuf.class).write(0, serializer);

            ProtocolLibrary.getProtocolManager().sendServerPacket(player, packet);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Bukkit.getLogger().info(ConsoleColor.ANSI_RED + "Error on TextPacket: " + ConsoleColor.ANSI_CYAN + " (" + exception.getMessage() + ")" + ConsoleColor.ANSI_RESET);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

The packet itself is sent unconditionally... But the handler on the mod doesn't work at all. The code for trying to create a handler is:
private static final String PROTOCOL_VERSION = "1";
    public static final SimpleChannel INSTANCE = NetworkRegistry.newSimpleChannel(
            new ResourceLocation("chilove", "main"),
            () -> PROTOCOL_VERSION,
            PROTOCOL_VERSION::equals,
            PROTOCOL_VERSION::equals
    );

    public static void register() {
//        INSTANCE.registerMessage(0, TextPacket.class, TextPacket::encode, TextPacket::decode, TextPacket::handle);

        int id = 0;
        INSTANCE.messageBuilder(TextPacket.class, id++, NetworkDirection.PLAY_TO_SERVER)
                .decoder(TextPacket::decode)
                .consumerMainThread(TextPacket::handle)
                .add();
        INSTANCE.registerMessage(id++, TextPacket.class, TextPacket::encode, TextPacket::decode, TextPacket::handle);
        INSTANCE.messageBuilder(TextPacket.class, id++, NetworkDirection.PLAY_TO_CLIENT)
                .decoder(TextPacket::decode)
                .consumerMainThread(TextPacket::handle)
                .add();
    }

TextPacket.class:
public class TextPacket {
    private String text;

    public TextPacket() { }

    public TextPacket(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public static TextPacket decode(FriendlyByteBuf buffer) {
        byte[] bytes = buffer.readByteArray();
        String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        ChiloveMod.LOGGER.info("Decoded text: {}", text);
        return new TextPacket(text);
    }

    public void encode(FriendlyByteBuf buffer) {
        byte[] bytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        buffer.writeByteArray(bytes);
    }

    public void handle(Supplier<NetworkEvent.Context> ctx) {
        ctx.get().enqueueWork(() -> {
            ChiloveMod.LOGGER.info("Received message: {}", text);
        });
        ctx.get().setPacketHandled(true);
    }
}


I've tried a LOT of options, and searched the internet for everything I can about SimpleImpl. Usually, when sending a packet, I get 2 errors in the console:

[15:15:32] [Netty Client IO #1/ERROR] [ne.mi.ne.si.IndexedMessageCodec/SIMPLENET]: Received invalid discriminator byte 84 on channel chilove:main
[15:15:32] [Render thread/WARN] [minecraft/ClientPacketListener]: Unknown custom packet identifier: chilove:main

I don't know what to do anymore, I've really rummaged through everything I can. I'm asking for help...
Minecraft Version: 1.19.3
Tried through events such as ClientboundCustomPayloadEvent.

Why do not use sendPluginMessage() instead of creating packet by yourself?

@Elikill58, how to handle this?

To simply send a CustomPayload packet from bukkit to the client, you can use the sendPluginMessage(plugin, channel, data) method like this :
Player p = ...;
String full_msg = "Text(" + message + ")";
byte[] data = full_msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
p.sendPluginMessage(MyPlugin.getInstance(), "chilove:main", data);

Arguments are:

The plugin you're using to send the message
The name of channel, formatted like that: project:name. If you are creating key with new MinecraftKey("a", "b"), so the channel will be a:b
The data to send


Yeah, I understand what you are talking about, but how to handle this packet in Forge? I tried this code, but from client I can't handle this

Are you sure thay are not cancelled by server ?

Yes. I receive message at client when got message, but got 2 errors (I wrote in the post above)
